# xcolor package disables cellspace package

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, incompatibility

I'm trying to add a vertical space in a table *after* each row. Currently I have the following files where the spacing works.

**My main file:**

```
% table-sep.tex
\documentclass{table-sep}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularcv}
    \hline
    2012-2016   &   Some text here which is a bit long \\
    \hline
    2010-2012   &   More text here \\
    \hline
\end{tabularcv}

\end{document}
```

**My working class file:**

```
% table-sep.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{table-sep}[2017/08/03 custom class v1]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{tabularx} 

\RequirePackage{cellspace}
\cellspacebottomlimit 30pt

% New environment with two columns
\newenvironment{tabularcv}{%
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{%
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{2.5 cm}}%
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Sl%
    }%
}%
{\endtabularx}%
```

**Result**
[image: Working situation]

However if I load the `xcolor` package by adding `\RequirePackage{xcolor}` to my `.cls` file, `\cellspacebottomlimit` has no effect. *Or* if I change the right column from a `l` to a `p{}` column in my `.cls` file:

```
@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Sl%
```

into

```
@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{5 cm}}%
```

`\cellspacebottomlimit` has no effect either. I then get:

[image: Not working]

**Non-working class file**

```
% table-sep.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{table-sep}[2017/08/03 custom class v1]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{tabularx} 

\RequirePackage{cellspace}
\cellspacebottomlimit 30pt

% New environment with two columns
\newenvironment{tabularcv}{%
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{%
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{2.5 cm}}%
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{5 cm}}%
    }%
}%
{\endtabularx}%

\RequirePackage{xcolor} %
```

---

**Edit 9 August 2017**

As mentioned in my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384664/xcolor-package-disables-cellspace-package#comment952437_384664) I've tried the same in one `.tex` file. With this code, if the package `xcolor` is used, it will disable `\cellspacebottomlimit`. If tried to place `\usepackage{xcolor}` at various parts in the preamble, but it gave the same result. Also with this code, the part `S{p{5 cm}}` does *not* disable the workings of `\cellspacebottomlimit`.

**Code**

```
%table-sep-v2.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx} 

\usepackage{cellspace}
\cellspacebottomlimit 30pt

% New environment with two columns
\newenvironment{tabularcv}{%
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{%
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{2.5 cm}}%
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{5 cm}}%
    }%
}%
{\endtabularx}%

% \usepackage{xcolor} % Uncommenting this will disable the space set by \cellspacebottomlimit

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularcv}
    \hline
    2012-2016   &   Some text here which is a bit long \\
    \hline
    2010-2012   &   More text here \\
    \hline
\end{tabularcv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you make testing more difficult by splitting your example into two files?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well my original problem this was the case. It did not occur to me to try it in one file. I can update the question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just tried it with one file, by loading the packages with `\usepackage`. In this case enabling `xcolor` causes `\cellspacebottomlimit` to have no effect (just as previously). However, now `@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{5 cm}}` does *not* disable `\cellspacebottomlimit`.

Comment: Just `color` suffices in order to show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises when `color` is loaded, because it makes `\color@endgroup` into a real group closing macro. In `cellspace.sty` we find

```
\renewcommand*{\@endpbox}{%
      \unless \ifcellspace@
        \@finalstrut \@arstrutbox
      \fi
      \par
      % Save the depth of the last line
      \global \cellspace@lastdp = \prevdepth
      \color@endgroup
      % \ifcellspace@ is only locally true, so we need to expand it before
      % \egroup stops it action
      \expandafter
    \egroup
    \ifcellspace@
    <irrelevant code here>
```

but in the case `color` is loaded, `\color@endgroup` already ends the effect of `\cellspace@true`. Solution: add another `\expandafter` before `\color@endgroup`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{color,xpatch}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{30pt}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@endpbox}{\color@endgroup}{\expandafter\color@endgroup}{}{\ddt}
\makeatother

% New environment with two columns
\newenvironment{tabularcv}{%
    \par\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{2.5 cm}}
        @{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2.5cm\relax}}
        @{}
    }
}
{\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularcv}
    \hline
    2012-2016   &   Some text here which is a bit long \\
    \hline
    2010-2012   &   More text here \\
    \hline
\end{tabularcv}

\end{document}
```

I also changed `tabularx` into `tabular`: it makes no sense to use the former without an `X` column and, moreover, the documentation of `cellspace` explicitly says it has not been tested with `tabularx`.

[image]